# Query s3 buckets on Android application

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I want my Android application to show the closest stores based on current gps location,
I have S3 instance which holds bucket for each store that contains two files image and Html file, that I want to show on the store page,
so far so good.

My question is how can I choose the nearest stores based on my gps location??
should I save another value Latitude and Longitude points for each bucket?
Do I need to use another aws service like RDS to be able to query and choose the right buckets to show, or maybe I can do sql query over S3 without using another AWS service.
Thank's,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:
You are probably talking about having a single bucket and different prefixes for each store. Having a bucket for each store, thus keeping 2 files in each bucket is definitely overkill.

On the nearest stores question:
You cannot perform a SQL query to S3.
Your solution really depends on the scale of your application. If you are talking about a web (or Internet) scale application (or even less than that), you definitely want to add stuff in front of S3. S3 is about storage, not about querying or performing computations.

My suggestion would be one of the below, depending on the size of your customer base and the size of your store base:
1- Small scale: assuming you have only a couple of customers and a couple (<100-like) stores. You can have a m1.small or similar EC2 instance in front of S3, keep your store list persisted on the instance storage (or on S3, for that matter) and perform your location-based query in a memory cache in your instance. You can implement it using the server technology of your choice (Python, Java, node.js).
2- Medium scale or larger: several (or millions) of clients, several (or millions) of stores: definitely stick to an application tier and a database tier. Your application tier can contain whichever AWS technology you prefer (several EC2 instances + an ELB; Elastic Beanstalk; etc.) and your DB tier should either be SQL (RDS being my recommendation) or NoSQL (DynamoDB, for instance). Model your stores into the database tier and make your app tier perform queries to it.

You can solve your problem in several ways, but my suggestion would be sticking to one of the above as a general architecture.

Comment: Thank's you helped my figure this issue. my data base will be pretty small at first, so I would choose The first option If i'm lucky I will switch to second one, about the S3 buckets I can use one bucket and each store will be hold in a folder.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Good luck!